# What is wrong with the table? I feel like the code is right but it's showing this empty space

Tags: html

I have 4 boxes here. It seems like there's an empty long one but I can't really understand where I went wrong. You can preview it in an editor, I think it'll be best.

```
<table border="1" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Mike Mike E-mail
Project Authroity
Email: mike@tech.net</td>
    <td>Mike E-mail
Project Authority
Nerd Specialist
Email: mail@domain.com</td>
    <td>Mike
Nerd Webmaster
Email: mike@nerd.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Nerd Force
Weird Specialist
Email: mail@domian.net</>
</table>
```

Comment: @emmanuel — End tags for those elements are optional

Comment: Hello, welcome to the site! You appear to be having difficulties asking good questions on StackOverflow. I recommend you read [the entire Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and head back when you have a specific, programming-related question.

Answer (score 0):

You have three cells in the first row.

You have one cell in the second row.

The "empty long one" is the space where the other two cells that should be in the second row should go.

---

The root cause appears to be that you are using a table for non-tabular data. It looks like you would be better off with a list and some CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You made a new row (tr) after 3 cells so the 4th cell is in a new row and the space of the missing two cells is empty.
also you have an empty closing tag at the end.

```
<table border="1" style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <td>Mike Mike E-mail
            Project Authroity
            Email: mike@tech.net
        </td>
        <td>Mike E-mail
            Project Authority
            Nerd Specialist
            Email: mail@domain.com
        </td>
        <td>Mike
            Nerd Webmaster
            Email: mike@nerd.com
        </td>
        <td> Nerd Force
            Weird Specialist
            Email: mail@domian.net
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

add coslapn to the last td:

```
<table border="1" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Mike Mike E-mail Project Authroity Email: mike@tech.net</td>
    <td>Mike E-mail Project Authority Nerd Specialist Email: mail@domain.com</td>
    <td>Mike Nerd Webmaster Email: mike@nerd.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"> Nerd Force Weird Specialist Email: mail@domian.net</td></tr
</table>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/msnz1z2m/1/)